# How do I hide this message output from knitr?

Tags: knitr

I'm trying to knit a markdown file and I couldn't hide this message for one of my chunks.

I tried using message=false,warning=false but none of them worked. Any help would be appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmYG2.png)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68883895/knitr-inline-code-message-false-not-working.